# how to create a generic procedure in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have already written code for a generic Carry Look-Ahead Adder. but I can't convert this code to be a procedure in a package. can anyone help me do it?

when I try to compile this code, it does not register `n` as a generic number.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Carry_Look_Ahead is

    Generic(n:integer:=4);

Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end Carry_Look_Ahead;

architecture Behavioral of Carry_Look_Ahead is

begin

process(A,B,Cin)

variable ci :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0);
variable P: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
variable G: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
variable si :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);     
          begin
       ci(0) := Cin;

FOR i IN 0 TO n-1 LOOP 

  P(i) := A(i) xor B(i);
  G(i) := A(i) and B(i);
  ci(i+1) := G(i) or (P(i) and G(i));
  si(i) := P(i) xor ci(i);

 END LOOP;
    S<=si;
    Cout<=ci(n);
end process;   

end Behavioral;
```

This is the error I get when I try to compile this code:

```
Unknown identifier "n".
```

Comment: What is the specific error message you get?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see. What simulator are you using? Which line you get the error message?

Comment: *but I can't convert this code to be a procedure in a package. can anyone help me do it?* Maybe you could show the source for the package? Also note this doesn't need to be a generic subprogram.

Comment: Instead of using a generic subprogram you could either require all the lengths of A, B and C match and use the range of one or use a generic package that's instantiated. Generic packages are more  commonly supported for synthesis while while generic subprograms are not. Tell us about your tool chain and provide the complete error message along with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Subprograms like procedures can have generic parameters. The syntax and usage is similar to generic entities or generic packages.

```
procedure cla
  generic (
    constant n  : in  positive
  )
  parameter (
    signal Cin    : in  STD_LOGIC;
    signal input1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
    signal input2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
    signal Sum    : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
    signal Cout   : out STD_LOGIC
  ) is
  variable c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0);
  variable P : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
  variable G : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
  variable s : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);  
begin
  c(0) := Cin;
  for i in 0 to n-1 loop
     P(i) := input1(i) xor input2(i);
     G(i) := input1(i) and input2(i);
     c(i+1) := G(i) or (P(i) and G(i));
     s(i) := P(i) xor c(i);
  end loop;
  Sum  <=s;
  Cout <=c(n);
end procedure;
```

Comment: @michael your attempted edit is wrong. Please see generics on subprograms in the VHDL LRM.

Answer (score -1):

my friend found a solution for this:

you can take an integer as a generic number. here is the finished `PROCEDURE`:

```
PROCEDURE cla (
      SIGNAL n               : IN  INTEGER; -- generic number
      SIGNAL Cin             : IN  STD_LOGIC;
      SIGNAL input1 , input2 : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
      SIGNAL Sum             : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
      SIGNAL Cout            : OUT STD_LOGIC
   ) IS
      VARIABLE c :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n downto 0);
      VARIABLE P: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
      VARIABLE G: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
      VARIABLE s :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 DOWNTO 0);  
   BEGIN    
      c(0) := Cin;
      FOR i IN 0 TO n-1 LOOP 
         P(i) := input1(i) XOR input2(i);
         G(i) := input1(i) AND input2(i);
         c(i+1) := G(i) OR (P(i) AND G(i));
         s(i) := P(i) XOR c(i);
      END LOOP;
      Sum<=s;
      Cout<=c(n);
   END cla;
```

Comment: n is pretty useless here, as you are assuming n is ralated to input1'length. If n  is greater than  input1'length-1, there will be an error in the for loop because the index into input1 and 2 will go out of bounds.

Comment: `n` can be class constant with an output signal of an array type. It can't be used in an allocator or n can be derived from one of the parameters (here `Sum`, you can't use a procedure in an allocator). Insure left and right order of `input1` and `input2` with aliases. Should be `c(i+1) := G(i) OR (P(i) AND c(i));`, same error in the original post, `ci` instead of `c`. The OP should provide a [mcve].  Tricky's error would be in the alias declarations during dynamic elaboration.